# webRTC настройка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, webrtc

купил ключ для webRTC, подскажите, чтобы клиенты общались на сайте через него, нужно устанавливать сервак? или можно как-то безе сервака на виртуальном хостинге его запустить?

```
<div class="web-box">
   <div id="TeacherWebRTC" style="width:320px;height:240px;border: 1px solid"></div>
   <input type="button" value="start" onClick="startTeacher()"/>
   <p id="status"></p>
</div>
```

//Teacher webRTC

```
var TeacherWebRTC;

function initTeacher(){
    Flashphoner.init();
    TeacherWebRTC = document.getElementById("TeacherWebRTC");
}

function startTeacher() {
    Flashphoner.createSession({urlServer: "wss://wcs5-eu.flashphoner.com:8443"}).on(Flashphoner.constants.SESSION_STATUS.ESTABLISHED, function (session) {
        //session connected, start streaming
        startStreamingTeacher(session);
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.SESSION_STATUS.DISCONNECTED, function () {
        setStatusTeacher("DISCONNECTED");
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.SESSION_STATUS.FAILED, function () {
        setStatusTeacher("FAILED");
    });
}

function startStreamingTeacher(session) {
    session.createStream({
        name: "stream222",
        display: TeacherWebRTC,
        cacheLocalResources: true,
        receiveVideo: false,
        receiveAudio: false
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.PUBLISHING, function (publishStream) {
        setStatusTeacher(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.PUBLISHING);
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.UNPUBLISHED, function () {
        setStatusTeacher(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.UNPUBLISHED);
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.FAILED, function () {
        setStatusTeacher(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.FAILED);
    }).publish();
}

function setStatusTeacher(status) {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = status;
}

//Learner webRTC

var LearnerWebRTC;

function initLearner(){
    Flashphoner.init();
    LearnerWebRTC = document.getElementById("LearnerWebRTC");
}

function start() {
    Flashphoner.createSession({urlServer: "wss://wcs5-eu.flashphoner.com:8443"}).on(Flashphoner.constants.SESSION_STATUS.ESTABLISHED, function (session) {
        //session connected, start streaming
        startPlaybackLearner(session);
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.SESSION_STATUS.DISCONNECTED, function () {
        setStatusLearner("DISCONNECTED");
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.SESSION_STATUS.FAILED, function () {
        setStatusLearner("FAILED");
    });
}

function startPlaybackLearner(session) {
    session.createStream({
        name: "stream222",
        display: LearnerWebRTC,
        cacheLocalResources: true,
        receiveVideo: true,
        receiveAudio: true
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.PLAYING, function (playStream) {
        setStatusLearner(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.PLAYING);
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.STOPPED, function () {
        setStatusLearner(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.STOPPED);
    }).on(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.FAILED, function () {
        setStatusLearner(Flashphoner.constants.STREAM_STATUS.FAILED);
    }).play();
}

function setStatusLearner(status) {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

да, вам надо ставить webcallserver